# How to add typing indicator in React webchat

Tags: reactjs, botframework, chatbot

I'm creating a bot application using bot framework web-chat and react js. I have almost completed the project. Now i just want to add typing indicator to my application. As i'm calling directline webchat to the application, How can i do that?

Comment: I am noob at react.js but know how you could achieve in web chat. By simply `sendTyping: true`

Comment: Duplicate of [how to perform Send 'Typing indicator in Botframework v4 chat application using React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389745/how-to-perform-send-typing-indicator-in-botframework-v4-chat-application-using/60394850#60394850).

Comment: Is my answer acceptable? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Answer (score 0):

Web Chat is a Direct Line client, which means it handles the user side of the conversation. If you want the bot to send a typing indicator for the user to see then you need to handle that on the bot side. You can learn how to send a typing indicator [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages#send-a-typing-indicator). You haven't said what SDK you're using, but you may also be interested in the typing middleware.

Web Chat does have a [`sendTypingIndicator`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/API.md) option but it's apparently for indicating to the bot that the user is typing in case the bot is programmed to use that information.